# When State value true, I want to execute a JavaScript code snippet. Conversely, when it's false, I need to remove this script code in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, performance, react-hooks

In my React.js project, I have a state variable assigned a Boolean value. When it's true, I want to execute a JavaScript code snippet. Conversely, when it's false, I need to remove this script code from my React project. How can I achieve this using the useEffect hook in React?

```
<!-- start Gist JS code–>
<script>
(function(d,h,w){var gist=w.gist=w.gist||[];gist.methods=[‘trackPageView’,‘identify’,‘track’,‘setAppId’];gist.factory=function(t){return function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);e.unshift(t);gist.push(e);return gist;}};for(var i=0;i<gist.methods.length;i++){var c=gist.methods[i];gist[c]=gist.factory©}s=d.createElement(‘script’),s.src=“url”,s.async=!0,e=d.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],e.appendChild(s),s.addEventListener(‘load’,function(e){},!1),gist.setAppId(“app
Id”),gist.trackPageView()})(document,‘head’,window);
</script>
<!-- end Gist JS code–>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

But you mentioned about the using `useEffect` hook.

I faced same issue recently and this is how I solved it. Hope this will help you.

I assume your `code snippet script` file name is `snipper-script.js`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

  

  const [boolValue, setBoolValue] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (boolValue) {
      const script = document.createElement('script');

      script.src = '/snipper-script.js';
      script.async = true;

      document.body.appendChild(script);

      return () => {
        document.body.removeChild(script);
      }
    }
  }, [boolValue]);
```